# I created checkboxlist, but I can't check them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

The result is checkbox list but I cant check them when I press mouse buton nothing happens.
Any help ?

This is my code in controler

```
ViewBag.Message = "Select Medias";
            var MediaInfo = CampaignManagementService.GetMedias((string)Session["ticket"]);
            List<MediaList> items = new List<MediaList>();
            foreach (var element in MediaInfo)
            {
                items.Add(new MediaList() { ID = element.Key, Name = element.Value });
            }
            ViewData["list"] = items;
```

And this is my code in view

```
<fieldset>
     <legend>@ViewBag.Message</legend>
     @{
         foreach (var item in ViewData["list"] as List<MediaList>)
         {
             <div class="form-horizontal well">
                 <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="controls">
                         <div class="checkbox-group">
                             <div class="adform-checkbox pull-left" tabindex=@item.ID></div>
                             <label>@item.Name</label>
                         </div>
                     <input class="input-small" type="text" id="input"> 
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         }
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create Tag</button>

     } </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form tag? 
Without it nothing would be posted anywhere.

Add:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in ViewData["list"] as List<MediaList>)
        {
            <div class="form-horizontal well">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="checkbox-group">
                            <div class="adform-checkbox pull-left" tabindex=@item.ID></div>
                            <label>@item.Name</label>
                        </div>
                    <input class="input-small" type="text" id="input"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create Tag</button>
}
```

Comment: Still cant check/select them

Answer (score 0):

This method of creating a checkbox doesn't look standard:

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <div class="adform-checkbox pull-left" tabindex=@item.ID></div>
    <label>@item.Name</label>
</div>
```

Have you tried using `Html.CheckBox()` instead? This will render the correct output for a checkbox e.g.

`<input type="checkbox" value="true" />`

So you could try

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
    @Html.CheckBox(@item.ID)
    <label>@item.Name</label>
</div>
```

EDIT:

When I'm using checkboxes, I tend to do the following. On my viewmodel class I have a collection of strongly-typed items:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<CheckBoxItem>();
        Items.Add(new CheckBoxItem { Id = 23, Text = "Hello" });
    }

    public IList<CheckBoxItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Text { get;set; }
}
```

The above is just for demo purposes. Next, in the view, I do this:

```
 for (int idx = 0; idx < Model.Items.Count;idx++ )
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[idx].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Items[idx].Checked)<label>@Model.Items[idx].Text</label>
    }
```

Then when you post the form,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    // viewModel.Items will contains the checkbox items.
}
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What is the error? I've added an expanded example of how I deal with checkboxes which might help you.